# What's wrong with the following C code- Struct and pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Something's wrong with the following function:

```
typedef struct Data1{
float result;
struct Data1* next;

} Data; 



Data* f(Data* info){
    Data item;
    item.result=info->result;
    item.next=info->next;

    return &item; 

}
```

I notice two things here:

1. The returned value is a pointer of local value. However it's still a pointer- the compiler gives a warning: function returns address of local variable. but would it really be a problem? ( I don't return a local value itself)
2. I believe that the main problem here is that this function suppose to copy the Data struct. it would be OK for the results value, but regarding the 'next' pointers, I believe that at the end of the call to the function the pointers would not be changed, Am I correct? It's like equalize two ints in a outside  function, should `*(item.next)=*(info->next);` solve the problem?

So what's the main problem here? is it both  1 and 2?

Answer (score 9):

> The returned value is a pointer of local value. However it's still a pointer- the compiler gives a warning: function returns address of local variable. but would it really be a problem? ( I don't return a local value itself)

That is the main problem. After the function returns, the local variable doesn't exist anymore. The space it occupied may be overwritten immediately or later, but you can't count on ever reading meaningful data from that address.

If you want to copy things, you have to return a pointer to `malloc`ed memory.

```
Data* f(Data* info){
    Data *item = malloc(sizeof *item);
    item->result=info->result;
    item->next=info->next;

    return item; 

}
```

But that has the drawback that now the caller has to `free` the memory allocated by `f`, so

```
Data* f(Data* info, Data* item){
    item->result=info->result;
    item->next=info->next;

    return item; 

}
```

with a pointer allocated by the caller.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I still don't feel comfortable with 'item->next=info->next', in the corrected function. It copies the adress of info's next to the adress of item's next. would it still be OK and remains after the function ends?

Comment: I don't understand what you're uncomfortable with. After copying, `item`'s `next` pointer contains the same address as `info->next`. That is either the address of a valid `Data` object, `NULL`, or a meaningless address. A meaningless address would be bad, but whether you have one or two `Data` objects pointing there is a minor detail. If it's `NULL`, that's okay. If it's the address of a `Data` object, either you want both to point to the same, then it's fine, or not. In that case, what do you want? Do you also want to copy the pointed-to object and make `item` point to the copy?

Answer (score 3):

The problem with returning pointers to local variables is that the space the local variables occupies will be reclaimed when the function returns, so the pointer no longer points to valid memory, or even memory used by other functions called later.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it would be a problem, since the returned pointer is useless: it's pointing at an object which no longer exists. Hence the warning.
2. Not sure I follow your reasoning here ... You are not changing anything in the `Data` passed in, so that's a problem if you expected it to.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, it's a problem, because your pointer now points to what used to be on your stack, but is no longer managed memory, which means another function call (or an  interrupt) will, with almost 100% certainty, begin mangling that memory.

2) I have no idea what you're asking here.

The main problem is that you're unclear on how memory works in C programs, which leads to constructs like this; not a ding, just an honest observation: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/14268 gives a relatively good overview and should serve you well.